# Convert 1 dimensonal list to 3 dimensional list

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a one dimensional list. I have to convert it to three dimensional list. How can i manage it ?

These are my lists.

```
 this.galleryImages = [
            {
                small: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/tasit-com/image/upload/c_thumb,w_640,h_480,e_sharpen:120/ccd97b3bb468f62162e1ce7557f25a06.jpg',
                medium: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/tasit-com/image/upload/c_thumb,w_640,h_480,e_sharpen:120/ccd97b3bb468f62162e1ce7557f25a06.jpg',
                big: 'https://imganuncios.mitula.net/renault_clio_2017_motorin_1_94_vade_orani_40_pe_i_n_48ay_taksi_t_duzgun_ti_caret_bunyesi_nde_3720113557242259227.jpg',

            },
            {
                small: 'https://imganuncios.mitula.net/renault_clio_2017_motorin_1_94_vade_orani_40_pe_i_n_48ay_taksi_t_duzgun_ti_caret_bunyesi_nde_3720113557242259227.jpg',
                medium: 'https://imganuncios.mitula.net/renault_clio_2017_motorin_1_94_vade_orani_40_pe_i_n_48ay_taksi_t_duzgun_ti_caret_bunyesi_nde_3720113557242259227.jpg',
                big: 'https://imganuncios.mitula.net/renault_clio_2017_motorin_1_94_vade_orani_40_pe_i_n_48ay_taksi_t_duzgun_ti_caret_bunyesi_nde_3720113557242259227.jpg'
            },
            {

                small: 'https://www.ihaleden.com/uploads/media/5c6f93d30a4a4.png',
                medium: 'https://www.ihaleden.com/uploads/media/5c6f93d30a4a4.png',
                big: 'https://www.ihaleden.com/uploads/media/5c6f93d30a4a4.png'
            }
        ]
```

My one dimensional list is selectedFilesList. I want to convert this list to 3 dimensional list and equal with the other list.

Comment: What do you mean by `3 dimensional`? Can you please edit the question to provide the desired structure as well?

Comment: That's it ?. Now can u help me Sir Harun ?

Comment: I mean do you wish to convert the array to something like `this.galleryImages['small'][0]` or `this.galleryImages['medium'][2]` rather than `this.galleryImages[0]['small']` or `this.galleryImages[2]['medium']`?

Comment: I have a 1d array. I want to convert it to 3d array repating each item for 3 times

Comment: I want to write each item of 1d array on 3d array (small,medium,big)

Comment: That's what I'm asking for actually :) I need to know the output structure of your 3d array to help you create the conversion function.

Comment: For example my 1d array is [a, b, c]  my 3d array should be   [ {small: a medium:a big:a,}   {small: b medium:b big:b}   { small: c medium:c big:c} ]

Comment: A 3-dimensional array would be something like `[[[0,1],[2,3]],[[4,5],[6,7]]]`.  You are not asking for a 3-dimensional array, so the term "3-dimensional" is only confusing things.  Consider removing all references to "3-dimensional" in your question.

Comment: Please consider editing the code in this question to constitute a [mcve].  This should include both the input and the desired output.  Right now you have only something like output in the question, along with a sketch of the input in a comment.  It looks like you want `inArr.map(x => ({small: x, medium: x, large: x}))` but we can't be sure without actual example code.  Good luck!

Comment: What have you tried, why doesn't it work and give an example of what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, using `map` function could help you like following:

```
const selectedFilesList = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

this.galleryImages = selectedFilesList.map((selectedFile) => {
    return {
        small: selectedFile,
        medium: selectedFile,
        big: selectedFile
    }
});
```

Hope this helps